# Importing csv-style text attachment from gmail into any kind of db/spreadsheet automatically?

Tags: mysql, csv, import, email

Every hour, I get a csv style file (delimited by `|` (pipe)) delivered via email to a gmail address with a few rows of stuff like `12X98XJ|75.00|0.00||0.00|23.15`

I'd like to automatically import to/update a database. I was thinking Google Docs "email to docs" functionality. Except helpfully they seem to have disabled that now.

I feel there MUST be a simple method in existence that does what I want.
Once it's in something where I can get at it with an API, it's plain sailing from then on. 
Even something as simple as importing to Amazon SimpleDB would do.
But a good half a day of Googling just leads down disappointing paths.

Two notes: 
All email functions are disabled on my server, so the .py scripts I found to retrieve from a local mail store file aren't going to work.

Don't ask me why the data is given to me in such a cack-handed way. It's historical. 
I seem to be working with people getting ready to migrate to windows 3.1

Comment: Could you use 'LOAD DATA INFILE'?  You could have it run with repeating script (ie AutoIt)?

Comment: Thanks John. Yes, I could. But how do I get the data file automatically from the attachment on the hourly email? **That's** the sticking point :)

Answer (score 0):

What about using the pair of fetchmail + procmail

Comment: fetchmail + procmail sounds like it might work for me. I'll let you know what I find next week. I can't find any info on tpair though.

Comment: That was a typo, was meant to be "the pair:".